# Making an array from values of a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays

Confusing title, not sure how to formulate myself. Example at the end, probably makes it easier to understand.

So, I have an array A_Main1 where each element is another array, A_Elem0, A_Elem1...A_ElemN

I want to make a new array where each element is the first element of every array A_ElemI in A_Main1

I've seen code of this before but can't remember how it's done. This is what part of my code looks like

```
latitudeInfo = [latitude1Info[], latitude2Info[]...latitudeNInfo[]]
#latitudeXInfo[0] = the actual latitude, latitudeXInfo[>0] are values in someway 
#connected to the latitude. So the 0th element of latitudeXInfo is always the latitude
```

I want to make a new array of all latitudes in latitudeInfo

```
possibleLatitudes = []
possibleLatitudes.append(latitudeInfo[i][0] for i in latitudeInfo)
```

Thinking that possibleLatitudes appends the 0th element of the i:th list in latitudeInfo but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `list-comprehension` that iterates through each list in `latitudeInfo` and takes the *first* element from that list with `l[0]`.

```
possibleLatitudes = [l[0] for l in latitudeInfo]
```

---

*Note that you are actually using `lists` here, and **not** `arrays`. This is a common misconception for people learning Python - especially coming from other languages. Basically the only time you use `arrays` in Python is with the `numpy` module. Everything else with square brackets `[]` is normally a `list`.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` in python like below. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map. It is similar to map in Javascript, Ruby or any other language.

`lambda` is an anonymous function that returns the specified criteria.
http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk

```
lats = list(map(lambda l: l[0], latitudeInfo))
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
>>> k = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
>>> list(map(lambda i: i[0], k))
[1, 3, 5]
```

Comment: You neither need `lambda` nor `map` for this task. In general list comprehensions should be preferred rather functional programming` methods.